# Can not create new paritiion for dual boot from Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot

[image: gparted]

I installed Arch Linux in my 500GB SSD. Now i want to dual boot it with Windows 11, so I'm trying to create a new 100GB unallocated partition from 185GB unused left

But seems like I can not do that, can anyone have a look and help me on this

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EXT4 filesystem has space for 186GiB of new files. The disk has no space. All of the disk is full of partitions, and the EXT4 filesystem is the same 463GiB size as the partition it was created in.

- First, backup your important files or clone the disk,
- Second, shrink the EXT4 filesystem that is on the partition.
- Third, resize the partition in the disk partition table(GPT or MBR).
- Fourth, make a new partition using all or part of the free disk space.

Step two and three must be done with precision or you can corrupt all of your data. Clone the drive or make a backup of important files before you start.

Detailed instructions for each step already exist online, so there is no need for me to duplicate that information here.

One big partition is not bad but it can cause the problem you have now. A common practice is to make a 40GiB partition for Arch and a separate partition just for /home (whatever size you want for your personal data). 40Gib is for a full general-purpose desktop install; a limited system could use less than 10GiB.

I like to make the home partition small to start and leave part of the disk unpartitioned so I can expand later, but I have a complicated multi-boot system with many disks and partitions that frequently change, some of which are mounted by more than one operating system. Several individual directories in my /home have their own partitions, this division makes backups and system changes less complicated.